# Modify slider value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, slider

I hope someone can solve my problem.

I've created a slider:

10000000

<-------O------>

But I want the slider to set a thousand separators and I don't know how to do that.

```
<h:outputText id="outputVolumen" value="#{createCredit.volumen}">
    <f:convertNumber />
</h:outputText>
<br style="display: block; margin: 5px 0" />
<p:slider id="slider" for="Volumen" minValue="100000" maxValue="5000000" step="10000" style="width:400px" display="outputVolumen" />
<h:inputHidden id="Volumen" value="#{createCredit.volumen}" />
```

Comment: at what moment do you want it updated? Only after sliding (stopping sliding) or also during sliding